# I want to get all anime related to specific Genre,

Tags: python, django

**model**

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.genre

class anime(models.Model):
    
    anime_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    Genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
    Season = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Episodes = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    IMDB_Rating = models.FloatField(null=True)
    #Image =

    def __str__(self):
        return self.anime_name
```

**view**

```
def g(request, G):

    animes = anime.objects.filter(Genre=G)
    x = {'animes': animes}
    return render(request, 'Anime/genre.html', x)
```

**urls**

```
path('genre/<G>/', views.g, name="main"),`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter on the `genre` field of the `Genre`, so:

```
def g(request, G):
    animes = anime.objects.filter(Genre__genre=G)
    x = {'animes': animes}
    return render(request, 'Anime/genre.html', x)
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`anime`</s> to `Anime`.

Comment: @Mario_z04 You should mark the answer as correct if it worked. Hey Willem, isn't `PascalCase` instead?